# "Eye floaters" in layman's terms

Tags: santé-et-médecine

"Eye floaters" is a generic term used to describe the specks or squiggly lines that you may see swimming across your line of sight when you move your eye quickly up, down or to the side, especially while looking at a blank, light background or up at the sky.

"Muscae volitantes" is how it is called in medical terms. I wonder if « les flotteurs d'œil » (albeit too literal) is the French equivalent that native speakers can easily associate with this medical condition?

I'm looking for a layman's term that does not elicit the « Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça ? » response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J'appelle ça des « mouches volantes » quand j'en parle avec mon ophtalmologiste. C'est aussi le [terme employé sur ophtalmissimo](http://www.ophtalmissimo.com/mouche.html).
Mais il semblerait que le terme propre non scientifique soit « corps flottants du vitré », et scientifique « Myodésopsie ». L'article  *[Floater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater)* de wikipedia renvoie à [Myodésopsie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myod%C3%A9sopsie) mais je ne connaissais pas le terme avant cette minute et je doute qu'il soit connu de beaucoup de gens. Donc restons sur « mouches volantes » pour *floaters*.

D'ailleurs le latin *Muscae volitantes* veut dire « mouches volantes ».

Comment: An interesting similarity. We say "moustiques volants {飛蚊症}" in Japanese.